# Only Allow 1 RSVP in Parties Example

Tags: meteor

Meteor Parties Example: http://www.meteor.com/examples/parties

What's the most efficient way of limiting 1 RSVP per user? I'd like to just modify the RSVP method somehow but unsure of how to go about it.

My general thought would be something like this:

```
if(Parties.find({rsvps:{user}}) > 1 )
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've basically got the right idea: add a check to the rsvp function in model.js. Here's the schema for the parties collection:

```
/*   Each party is represented by a document in the Parties collection:
    owner: user id
    x, y: Number (screen coordinates in the interval [0, 1])
    title, description: String
    public: Boolean
    invited: Array of user id's that are invited (only if !public)
    rsvps: Array of objects like {user: userId, rsvp: "yes"} (or "no"/"maybe")
*/
```

To check if a user already has an rsvp, you'd want to add a line to that function like this:

```
if (Parties.find({'rsvps.user': this.userId}).count()) return;
```

This'll basically work. There's a minor race condition, though, where one user can call rsvp twice in quick succession, this check can pass for both updates, and then he'll be rsvp-ed twice. There are ways around that (ex: some form of two-phase commit...) but they're more involved.